# how to create a graph with labels with excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of some 50 unique items in column A. The corresponding items in column B are not unique. The recommended graph, which I get gives me a count of my unique items on x-axis and six categories on my y-axis. While y-axis is labled with the name of the cell members, the x-axis is not. Is there a way to label each bar with the content of the cells, which contribute to it?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on any of the bars, and choose 'Add Data Labels'. Then Right-click again and chose 'Format Data Labels'.

You will get a pop-out, where you can chose under 'Label Options', between: 'Series Name', 'Category Name', and 'Values'.

Try either one to see which one gives you what you want; note that you can check multiple boxes simultaneously to get more data:
[image]